# Can I temporarily ground an outlet in my home to use a pressure washer outside it?

Tags: grounding

Can I temporarily ground an outlet by attaching a wire to its central screw and then to a grounding rod situated outside my house?  I want to use an electrical pressure washer, but it requires a ground that none of my outlets have.

Comment: The pressure washer "*requires*" a ground, or has a three prong cord?

Comment: If an installed 3-prong outlet adapter doesn't achieve a ground, you have worse problems then dirty stuff. Install a GFCI.

Comment: Ground systems are dependent on being bonded to a central point so you don't develop differential voltages. GFCI in answer below tests for having a differential in current, if you develop a short to ground, the hot passes more current than the neutral and the GFCI immediately shuts off. It measures this differential current and trips to disconnect power when it detects a ground fault in the 4-6mA range.

Answer (score 4):

My solution for this sort of thing: I built a "power strip" box containing a GFCI. That provides protection as good as or better than a safety ground, in a portable form. (If you do this often I'd suggest actually permanently replacing that outlet with a GFCI. My outdoor outlets are powered via a gfci in the basement.)